# How do I instantiate a static grid of UI images in Unity optimally?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, gameobject

Here's the setup:

- A Prefab which contains a gameobject with a child image (A CellPrefab). When a Cell is instantiated it gets a random color.
- An X by Y grid of Cells.

Here's the prefab:
[image: Cell Prefab]

Where base is a gameobject with an image:
[image]

and pixel is a 1x1 white dot.

And the code for a Cell:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Cell : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Image>().color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
    }
}
```

Code for the Grid:

```cs
public class Grid
{
  public Grid(int width, int height, float cellSize, Cell CellPrefab, Canvas canvas)
   {
      this.cellSize = cellSize;
      oneCell = CellPrefab;
      gridArray = new int[width,height];
      cellContentArray = new Cell[width,height];

      for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      {
         for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++)
         {
            CreateCell(x, y, GetWorldPosition(x,y) + new Vector2(cellSize,cellSize)*0.5f, canvas);
         }
      }
   }

      private void CreateCell(int x, int y, Vector2 position, Canvas canvas)
   {
      var cell = Object.Instantiate(oneCell, position, Quaternion.identity, canvas.transform);
      cell.transform.localPosition = position;
      cell.name = $"[{x},{y}]";
      cellContentArray[x, y] = cell;
   }

     private Vector2 GetWorldPosition(int x, int y)
   {
      return new Vector2(x * cellSize - (Width*cellSize/2f),y * cellSize - (Height*cellSize/2f));
   }

}
```

Note that the objects that the grid contains of will never be moved, resized or otherwise translated and are thus static.

The **challenge** is that the size of the grid is unmangeable. In my use-case I can go no lower than a 100 by 100 grid. This means that using my current method I'm instantiating 10.000 gameObjects just to show the grid and I'm rendering 40.000 tris at this point. The Unity Editor is unresponsive for a long time when trying to select any of the cells in the grid.

[image: 25 by 25 grid]

As you can see on the screenshot, each cell is only a square image with a color (randomized).

I would **appreciate** some pointers or ways of dealing with a large amount of gameobjects in Unity or if there is a whole other way I can go about this problem. Maybe a way to "squash" all the images to one big but still keep information about the different cell positions and object information.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide the screenshot for us to see how your prefab is defined (so that we could see all it's definition which is available on the right side of your Unity's editor.

Comment: Sure, I've added additional info.

Comment: Just wandering, is it necessary for your Cell to have a CanvasRenderer too? I'm just being curious, it's not possible to remove this Component?

Comment: The Image component depends on it. So I cannot delete without deleting the Image component

Comment: Yes, but I was asking about "Cell", not "base" node.

Comment: Ahh sorry. No I don't think that is necessary. I have removed it

Comment: If that's unmangeable you will have to probably find some another approach. Maybe not using Canvas but drawing it in 3d as simple planes. All those rectangles should be visible at the same time? If not then maybe you could try using some spatial subdivision algorithms

Comment: Eventually you could try drawing all those rectangles by yourself, using one instance of Canvas. Maybe this approach would be more efficient. Those are my ideas, but I'm not sure if they are feasible or will make any difference to the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rendering this through UI is the wrong abstraction.

You need to think of it this way:

1. How can I store information for cells?
2. How can I show cells to the user?

These are two very different problems, and you're conflating them.

---

## 1) How can I store information for cells?

In a simple 2d Array.

You have a `Cell` class.

Each cell should probably have a display color as a public property of the Cell class.

Then, your grid of cells is just a `Cell[,]` object.

---

## 2) how can I show this to users?

Create a black image with same dimensions as 2D cell array
Loop through your 2D cell array.

for each x,y cell, you change the image's x,y pixel color to the cell's color.

---

Done. Now you have 1 game object, an image of the same dimensions as your 2D array.